# CSS triangles: Thin border between container and triangle (iPad / Landscape iPhone)

Tags: iphone, css, ipad

I'm running into a very specific issue using CSS triangles:

I've created buttons that work perfectly on desktop browsers (ie9+, ff, chrome, safari), and on iPhones in portrait mode... The issue exists on iPads (retina and non-retina), as well as iPhones in landscape. The button renders with a line between the main container and the css triangle(s) that I've got in place.

Here's a screenshot on imgur:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsJz2.jpg

Here's the code I'm using:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="cta-watch large"><span>BUTTON SHAPE</span></a>
```

CSS (there are potentially a few non-relevant styles included because this is pasted from a larger file):

```
.cta-watch {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        padding: 0 10px;
        background-color: #91a1a8;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        color: white;
        font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-style: normal;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 30px;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        line-height: 40px;
        text-decoration: none;
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
    .cta-watch.large {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        width: 34px;
        height: 32px;
    }

.cta-watch.large:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.cta-watch.large.arrow-left::after, .cta-watch.large.arrow-right::after {
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}

.cta-watch.large span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  text-indent: -99999px;
}

.cta-watch.large span:before {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  content: '';
  border-color: transparent transparent #91a1a8 transparent;
  border-width: 0 27px 14px 27px;
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
  top: -14px;
  left: 0;
}

.cta-watch.large span:after {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  content: '';
  border-color: #91a1a8 transparent transparent transparent;
  border-width: 14px 27px 0 27px;
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -14px;
  left: 0;
}

.cta-watch.large:before {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  content: '\25BA';
  color: white;
  font-family: arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin-left: 3px;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 34px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

JSBin showing code demo here: http://jsbin.com/ocaGeja/1

Any help would be greatly appreciated - Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the same issue in Chrome for Windows, changing the zoom level.

At least in this situation, it is solved changing this value to decimal:

```
.cta-watch.large span:before {
    ...
    top: -13.7px;
```

May be that can help you ?

Another posibility would be to change the way you create the hexagon. Instead of the triangles way, you can try the multi-background way:

```
.hexagon {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    font-size: 80px;
    height: 2em;
    width: 1.732em;
    background-size: 50.5% 50.5%; 
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(300deg,transparent 33%, red 0%), -webkit-linear-gradient(240deg,transparent 33%, red 0%),                        -webkit-linear-gradient(60deg,transparent 33%, red 0%),                        -webkit-linear-gradient(120deg,transparent 33%, red 0%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right;
}
```

It's responsive em based, so that it can fit your need quite well.

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bAhLS/)

Comment: Thanks vals. I'm not sure this is quite what I need, because it seems that changing it to -13.7 rounds the value down to -13px. This results in the edges of the rectangular portion of the button to stick out a bit :( I'll play with this a bit more though to see if I can work something out. Thanks again for the suggestion.

Comment: Thanks Vals! This is great, and it'll get me close to what I need in terms of browser support... I'll still need a fallback (using triangles most likely) for IE9 (thankfully that's the oldest version of IE I need to support here).